# Mostrar imagen [URL] almacenada en +html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

agradezco a todas las personas que de una u otra manera han colaborado  de corazón mil gracias!

En esta oportunidad, solicito ayuda para mostrar una imagen almacenada en MYSQL en formato URL, y ponerla en el html en img src="AQUI DEBERIA QUEDAR".

Para una mejor explicación dejo la fracción del código que me genera el HTML:

```
 var html = '';

                    for(var count = 0; count < data.review_data.length; count++)
                    {
                       html += '<div class="row mb-3">';
                                                       [     AQUI DEBERÍA QUEDAR LA IMAGEN ]
                        html += '<div class="col-sm-1"><div  class="img-circle" img src=""  <h3 class="text-center">'+data.review_data[count].user_name+'</h3></div></div>';

                        html += '<div class="col-sm-11">';

                        html += '<div class="card">';

                        html += '<div class="card-header"><b>'+data.review_data[count].user_name+'</b></div>';

                        html += '<div class="card-body">';
```

La respuesta de la base de datos la obtengo así:

```
$query = "
    SELECT * FROM avatrade 
    ORDER BY review_id DESC
    ";

    $result = $connect->query($query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $review_content[] = array(
            'user_name'     =>  $row["user_name"],
            'user_review'   =>  $row["user_review"],
            'rating'        =>  $row["user_rating"],
            'user_avatar' => $row['user_avatar'],
            'datetime'      =>  date('l jS, F Y h:i:s A', $row["datetime"])
        );
```

Ahora no sé como escribir para poner dentro de img src esa variable, he tratado con: `src="<? php echo $row ['user_avatar']?>"` pero no me ha funcionado.

Nuevamente mil gracias por su colaboración!

Comment: y si le pones `data.review_data[count].user_avatar`?

Comment: aunque igual tienes cosas raras... aqui en este código falta algo: `<div  class="img-circle" img src=""  <h3 class="text-center">` declaras un div, pero tienes una propiedad img y una src? no deberia img ser un elemento nuevo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP estás creando la propiedad `'user_avatar' => $row['user_avatar']` y es la que debes usar para mostrar la imagen. Adicionalmente, te recomiendo usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para tener un código más legible, sin concatenar y pudiendo incluir variables con `${variable_u_objeto.propiedad}`:

```
let html = '';
for(let count = 0; count < data.review_data.length; count++) {
    html += `<div class="row mb-3">
                 <div class="col-sm-1">
                     <div  class="img-circle" img src="${data.review.data[count].user_avatar}">
                     <h3 class="text-center">${data.review_data[count].user_name}</h3>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-11">
                 <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-header">
                         <b>${data.review_data[count].user_name}</b>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card-body">
                         Aquí más contenido
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>`;
}
```